# Sprite loading in compass

Tags: compass-sass

I am learning how to use Compass from a tutorial that is about 4 years old. My problem is that the sprites are not loading at all, although the directory listed in the error is the correct location of the sprites.

I receive these two error messages:

```
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (12:12:47:223 | error, network)
   at http://localhost:8383/images/spr-sf52e1e883c.png
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (12:13:45:615 | error, network)
   at http://localhost:8383/images/pitch-s4b17d3ee2e.png
```

This looks like the correct address to me given the directory structure of my project.  See the image attached.  [image: project map]

I discovered either my sprite files are in the incorrect location or my generated css is incorrect in where the sprite files are located. Below is the code generate in the CSS.

```
/* ===================================================== */
/* Sprites
/* ===================================================== */
.spr-sprite, header h1 {
  background-image: url('/images/spr-sf52e1e883c.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.pitch-sprite, .pitch.left div, .pitch.middle div, .pitch.right div {
  background-image: url('/images/pitch-s4b17d3ee2e.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

What works is to back up one directory in the calling the sprite:

```
 .spr-sprite, header h1 {
     background-image: url('../images/spr-sf52e1e883c.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

 .pitch-sprite, .pitch.left div, .pitch.middle div, .pitch.right div {
     background-image: url('../images/pitch-s4b17d3ee2e.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Now I can see sprites.

What I don’t know is where to look to resolve this issue and I hope my description is enough for someone to offer me advice

All of my research points to using the configuration parameter “relative_assests = true”, to resolve this but I can’t seem to convince my compass project to give me relative directories “../” for my sprite images.  I compile my sprites with this configuration file.

```
 /* ===================================================== */
 /* Sprites
 /* ===================================================== */
 @import "spr/*.png";
 @import "pitch/*.png";
```

And this is my config.rb

```
 # Require any additional compass plugins here.
 # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 project_path = File.expand_path("..",File.dirname(__FILE__))

 # Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
 # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 relative_assets = true

 http_images_dir = "images"

 http_path = "/"
 css_dir = "css"
 sass_dir = "scss"
 images_dir = "images"
 javascripts_dir = "js"


 # Output style and comments
 # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 # You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
 # output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed
 # Over-ride with force compile to change output style with: compass compile --output-style compressed --force
 output_style = :expanded
 #environment = :development

 line_comments = false
 cache = true
 color_output = false # required for Mixture

 require 'sass-globbing'

 # Obviously
 preferred_syntax = :scss

 # SASS core
 # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 # Chrome needs a precision of 7 to round properly
 Sass::Script::Number.precision = 7
```

I wonder if anyone sees a problem

Answer (score 0):

There is something I don't know what incorrect in the config.rb file.  By substituting one from another tutorial it worked.